# Elasticsearch Search query with multiple filters

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Hello guys I am new to elastic search but I have gone through the basic ElasticSearch 5.1 documentation.

**Problem in one line:**

Search is successful but filters are not working properly.

## Mapping datatypes

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {"type": "string"},
        "description": {"type": "string"},
        "slug": {"type": "string"},
        "course_type": {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
        "price": {"type": "string"},
        "categories": {"type": "keyword", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
        "tags": {"type" : "keyword"},
        // "tags": {"type" : "keyword", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
        "status": {"type" : "string","index" : "not_analyzed"},
    }
}
```

As noted by @Darth_Vader I tried mapping as well. Following is my mapping

## Document in index (Req-1)

```
....
{
    "_index": "learnings",
    "_type": "materials",
    "_id": "582d9xxxxxxxx9b27fab2c",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "title": "Mobile Marketing",
      "slug": "mobile-marketing",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend hendrerit vehicula.",
      "categories": [
        "Digital Marketing"
      ],
      "tags": [
        "digital-marketing",
        "mobile-marketing"
      ],
      "status": "published"
    }
},
...
```

Like above I have like hundred documents in an index

## SEARCH QUERY FULL that I am using

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
             "multi_match" : {
              "query" : "mobile",
              "fields" : [ "title^5", "tags^4", "categories^3" ],
              "operator": "and"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    {"term" : {"status": "published"} }
                ]
             }
         }
    }
}
```

- In the above query the most important search criteria/filter is **`{"term" :
  {"status": "published"} }`**. Every search result must meet this
  requirement.
- Now from the list of results, I want to filter more. So say I want to get only `documents` which has **`mobile-marketing`** as a **`tag`**. My document **(Req-1)** has this **`tag`** (`mobile-marketing`)

## NOW the problem is:

If I modify my **Search Query** and add my required ***filter*** like the following below: I get NO search result (hits = 0) even though my document **(Req-1)** has **`mobile-marketing`** as a **`tag`**

```
"filter": {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            {"term" : {"status": "published"} },
            {"term" : {"tags": "mobile-marketing"} }
        ]
     }
 }
```

> **BUT** if I change the filter `{"tags": "mobile-marketing"}` **TO** `{"tags": "mobile"}`, I get the required document **(Req-1)** as result.

**I want** to get the same document using this filter: **`{"tags": "mobile-marketing"}`**. So where am I doing wrong?

> What modification does my search query need?

Thanks

Comment: [For people having similar issue].The above procedure and the related code works, make sure you use proper index name and index types at time of mapping and other related operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your **mapping** look for `tags`?

Seems like you've got your mapping for `tags` field as *analyzed*. What *analyzed` does is, from the [books](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2):

> First analyze the string and then index it. In other words, index this
>   field as full text.

So it analyzes it first, where the value looks like **mobile-marketing**. Hence it'll store mobile and marketing separately because of the hyphen in the middle and it'll be tokenized into tokens. ie: it'll store **mobile** and **marketing** into two different tokens.

Whereas if it's *not_analyzed*:

> Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as
>   specified. Do not analyze it.

So this will basically store the value as it is without analyzing it, which should  do the trick in your case. Maybe you should have a look at this [point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_query_with_text) as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh thanks @Darth_vader, I didnt do any mapping, I simply created  an index and started populating the document without any mapping. I guess I need to do the mapping and make it  "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed" . Let me check if it works. Thanks

Comment: Yup sure, let me know if it works @SiddharthaChowdhury.

Comment: Hey @Darth_Vader, I tried mapping and added my mapping details in the question . But it didnot worked. Its behaving the same way.

Comment: What if you have **tags** *type* as `text`?

*"tags": {"type" : "text", "index" : "not_analyzed"}*

Comment: And if it the type is **keyword** you don't have to explicitly set `not_analyzed` since **keyword** is suppose to have it by default.  Could be [helpful](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#breaking_50_mapping_changes). Let me know if it works.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much @Darth_Vader. Your suggestion and links really saved my day. Actually I forgot to specify the index type at time of mapping. Totally my carelessness. Well thanks again for answering and pointing the right direction. [Already upvoted] [Accepted]